# Integral Inequality from UCLA Math GRE Week 2, Exercise 23

Tags: calculus

I'm reading UCLA maths GRE prep course, and I'm having trouble with the following inequality:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\int^\pi_0\frac{dy}{1+(y+n\pi)^4\sin^2(y)}\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\int^\pi_0\frac{dy}{1+(n\pi)^4\sin^2(y)}$$

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but I would only assume I could remove the y if I know that $n\pi$ is greater than one, which in the case of $n=0$, it's not, so I would have to show the following right?

$$\int^\pi_0\frac{dy}{1+y^4\sin^2(y)}\leq\int^\pi_0 dy = \pi$$

Which should be the case since $y^4\sin^2(y)\geq0$.

Since the notes have no justification, I want to make sure I'm on the right track.

Thanks!

Comment: $1+(X)^2\geq 1$ for real $X$. In the second inequality, your denominator is bigger than 1, so you might as well bound it by 1. In the first inequality, if $0\leq y\leq \pi$, then $(y+n\pi)\geq n\pi)$, so a similar statement holds.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If this is for the math GRE, which has no proofs, what is the goal of the problem? I think the intuition is probably clear, but the proof may not be obvious. Is the goal to just review math in general and this is one of the questions?

Comment: @zugzug This is only a part of the problem on the problem set. Although GRE Math doesn't require proofs. I thought it would be useful for me to understand the reasoning in between each line.

Comment: Oh okay. That's what I figured was the case.

Comment: @Integrand Thanks! I think I really had to just write it out to make sure. I think I really just had to check the case $n=0$.

Comment: A nice thing about this problem is that the integral is already inside the sum. Hence, the inequality holds for all partial sums. The sum terms are positive so the sequence of partial sums is monotone increasing.  Therefore, without even knowing whether there's convergence or not, it makes sense that the inequality would hold in the limit.